# How to show Javascript variable inside input box ,so that i cant post it in html form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

http://jsfiddle.net/t32h0gj4/4/

how to show variable inside input box`<b id="smsCount"></b> SMS (<b id="smsLength"></b>) Characters left
<br />
<input type= "text" id= "smsCount" ></input>
 <textarea id="smsText" style="width:400px;height:200px"></textarea>`

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/t32h0gj4/5/

Changes:
HTML: `change id="smsCount"` to `class="smsCount"` (id's need to be unique)

JavaScript: change the selector to `.smsCount` and further below also call the jQuery `.val()` function to set the input box.

Comment: thank you very much , i dont know java and i had wasted two days on this